# <img> tag is not pulling up the image passed as props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I created one data file and I added Img name as one object.
[data.js]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG385.png
In fact, these images are also stored in the Image folder of my project.
But when I pass this data through Component as props, the image is not loading up -
[Props data]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHByK.png
[Props]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Jqk.png

Console also shows that the Img data is getting pulled correctly!
[Console]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pkbt.png

If I manually enter img address under src the img gets pulled properly. Why I am not able to use it using props?

Comment: you know what's better than images of code? .... code

Comment: Try to put code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) and share the link.

Comment: You can find this code here. Go to <Card /> Component. I have added my comments there. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/airbnb-clone-dbqgg0?file=/src/Components/Card.js

Comment: @AmjedAli I have added the code link

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In React, image tags are a bit different. This isn’t really React’s fault, but more a problem of where the images will reside on the server after the app is built.

### Two Ways to Include an Image in a React Component

With React, since there’s a build step, you need a way to include the image. There are 2 main ways to do that.

#### Option 1: `import` the image into the component

Put the image file somewhere under the `src` folder. This alone will not automatically make it available, so you have to import the image into the React component where you’re using it.
Wherever you want to display the image, render your img tag and pass that variable as the src:

```js
import katie from "../../Images/katie-zaferes.png";

function ImageExample () {
   return <img src={katie} alt="Katie profile" />
}
```

#### Option 2: Put the image in the `public` directory

You can put the image file in the `public` folder (or if this is not Create React App… then any folder that will be copied to the server).

Then, assuming your server is treating the `public` folder as the “root” directory (/), then your images will be available relative to that – just like with plain HTML.

So if you had an image at `public/images/wedding-photography.png`, you could display that image this way:

```js
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src="images/wedding-photography.png" alt="Wedding photography example"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```